# Wordpress Адаптивный thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

Данный код создает thumbnail 150x100 изображения к примеру с размером 500х1000 он берет центр и режет на 150 высоту. Как создать thumbnail с адаптивным высотой ? пример так: https://i0.shbdn.com/photos/64/57/12/thmb_688645712rnn.jpg

```
$image_src_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'full');
$image_src       = bfi_thumb($image_src_array[0], array(
'width' => $width,
'height' => $height,
'crop' => true
));

pacz_thumbnail_image_gen($image_src, $width, $height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `add_image_size()`, поместив её в `functions.php` активной темы WordPress:

```
<?php
// 150 в ширину и без ограничения в высоту
add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 150, 9999 );
```

Для вывода на сайте укажите этот новый размер:

```
<?php
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'category-thumb' );
```